# Looking for the fastest way to divide by 2

Tags: c++, floating-point, fixed-point

I've searched half the day and found some very interesting things about using fixed point data types and bit shifting in C++ to accomplish division operations while avoiding floating point math. However, I have only been able to understand a small fraction of it and I can't seem to get anything to work.

All I'm wanting to do is to take two integers, ad them up, and divide by two to get the average. I need to be able to do this very quickly though, since I'm interpolating camera pixel data on an Arduino and I also have other operations to do.

So I'm confused about shifting in general. Say the integer I want to divide by two is 27. Half of 27 is 13.5. But no matter what fixed point datatype I try,  I can only get 13 as an output. For example:

```
uint8_t  x = 27;
Serial.println(  x >> 1 );
```

returns 13

There's got to be some simple way to do this, right?

Comment: The fastest way is to use plain division, and then let the compiler optimize it.

Comment: As for your problem, how would you represent a floating point value with decimals, like `13.5`, as an ***integer***?

Comment: Think about number in base 10 - for example 1023, if we shift it right, we divide by 10 - 102, what could be simpler?

Comment: Integer data types aren't _fixed-point_, you're seriously confusing something here.

Comment: Wow, thanks guys. Sorry I asked.

Comment: If you add the integers and then don't divide, the result is already in Q1 format and thus can represent halves. Of course you then have to carefully interpret the result as being in the Q1 format.

Comment: So this is a legitimate question. If the concepts involved were crystal clear to the asker, he wouldn't need to ask it. Why all the downvotes?

Comment: @Cameron Poor research perhaps?

Comment: @Cameron, I do not know why it was downvoted. It is an OK question. I wouldn't upvote it on it's own, but upvoted to offset the downvotes.

Comment: @SegeyA You shouldn't upvote to just "to offset the downvotes".  That literally defeats the point of the voting system.

Comment: @SergeyA _"but upvoted to offset the downvotes"_ I'm not sure that's a good reason for upvoting.

Comment: Sometimes it seems like that offsets the broken nature of the voting.

Comment: @Eddge, well, this is what I do. If I see a question is (in my view) unjustly dowvoted, I upvote it.

Comment: @SergeyA This question to you may seem to be unjustly downvoted, but do you know the actual reason they downvoted? no you only have an assumption as to why it was downvoted.  To someone this may be a good question, and they should upvote it.

Comment: Just remember, some of us do not have a background in programming and therefore don't know where to look, where our blind spots are, or even what there is to know. When you see a question that so obviously comes from someone like that, don't take it as an opportunity to get your panties in a bunch.

Comment: @Eddge they should leave a comment with why they downvoted if they don't want someone to balance it out. Otherwise their downvote is pretty much useless.

Comment: @Eddge, yes. You downvote - you explain.

Comment: I downvoted this question because of a couple reasons. Mostly, it's because the "should I bitshift instead of divide by 2" question has been asked *a lot*. Also, this question is not actually about that. It's basically, "When I divide 27 by 2, why do I get 13 instead of 13.5?" That question has also been asked *a lot*. Furthermore, the OP uses the term "fixed point" but does not appear to have any understanding of what fixed point is. Any good explanation of fixed point arithmetic will explain how to do the arithmetic operations. TL;DR: this question does not show any research effort

Comment: I was very explicit in the mount of research I put into this. I clearly stared I spent half the day. Do you know what that gets you when you start basically from scratch? Think back to when you first started. How much did you know after four hours?

Comment: @SergeyA I didn't downvote this question.  so what do I have to explain?

Comment: @Taztingo By that same concept everyone that upvotes should have to explain why they upvoted.  There is no reason for multiple people to say "Hey I downvoted because blah." if there is already a comment that states why they downvoted.  The fact of the matter is, if you see a question with downvotes, and you don't think its a good question, but not that it's a bad question doesn't mean you upvote it, SO has systems in place to detect for people that just go inbetween threads and just downvotes them.

Comment: @Eddge It also doesn't mean you downvote it, which people do. I mentioned a comment is required because downvoting results in a negative action. It also applies to to a real world scenario. A disagreement should always explain each person's standing especially if it has negative consequences. Next time you go to a meeting, and you disagree with someone tell them that their idea "sucks". See how well that plays out for you.

Comment: @Taztingo your right you should explain why you downvote it, unless there is already a few people stating the same reason,  3 people telling you to show research is enough you dont need 10 people to say the same thing, and spamming the comment section like we are.  Perhaps we should take this to chat?

Comment: @Taztingo I go to meetings quite often and I tell people why their ideas are bad, how about you go to a meeting, listen to someone tell a person their idea is bad and why it's bad, and then you reiterate over it.  It does nothing but waste time.

Comment: @Eddge Right, you tell them why and that's my point haha. You don't just say "It sucks"/downvoting. Yeah we can bring it to chat.

Comment: @Taztingo https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150438/looking-for-the-fastest-way-to-divide-by-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you only get 13 is because you are actually cutting off the least significant bits when you bit shift. Since you are cutting them off, there is no remainder to check. If you are interested in what your remainder is, you could do something like:

```
uint8_t x = 27;
Serial.println((x - (x >> 1) - (x >> 1));
```

(x - (x >> 1)) should give 14 here.

it would be pretty simple to add .5 to a number once you determine whether the remainder is 1.

Comment: Hey, thanks man. I had not seen this particular trick anywhere I've looked so far. All I need is that .5 precision, so it would be easy to add that if needed on the fly without doing any actual division. I guess I steel need my ending array to be in a floating point format to hold that first decimal, but I won't actually be doing any math with it.

Comment: You can also check the LSB bit for even and odd, that should be fast enough. From my understanding the modulus 2 operation can be optimized by the compiler to a bitwise-and: `if(x & 0x01) { /* odd */}` or if trusting optimizer `if(x % 2) { /* odd */} `

Answer (score 7):

Fixed point does give you a way to represent 13.5. The Wikipedia article on the Q number format is informative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)

Think of it this way: You keep using integers, but instead of taking them at face value, divide them all implicitly by a power of 2 to obtain their semantic value.

So, if using an unsigned byte as your base type (values between 0 and 255, inclusive), you might implicitly divide by 2**3 (8). Now to represent 27, you need an integer set to 27*8=>216. To divide by two, you shift one to the right; now your integer is 108, which when divided by the implicit denominator of 8 gives 13.5, the value you're expecting.

You have to realize that fixed-point number systems (and floating point too, though it's less immediately evident) still have limits, of course; certain operations will overflow no matter what you do, and some operations cause a loss of precision. This is a normal consequence of working with limited-size types.

Comment: Thank you Cameron. I saw some material on Q type but at the time I couldn't tell whether or not it applied to the problem. 

I should be able to do this same thing if my two starting integers have values from 0 to 1023. I guess I would just need to pick a data type to put them in and find a number besides 8 to go with that data type.

Comment: Right. Values 0-1023 fit into 10 bits, plus you need one bit after the decimal point for your .5 (and it's helpful to have another bit too on the high end for adding without worrying about overflow), so a uint16_t with implicit division by 2 (Q1) would be plenty.

Answer (score 2):

> Say the integer I want to divide by two is 27. Half of 27 is 13.5. But
>   no matter what fixed point data type I try, I can only get 13 as an
>   output.

From wikipedia Fixed-Point Arithmetic:

> The scaling factor is usually a power of 10 (for human convenience) or
>   a power of 2 (for computational efficiency).

You actually mentioned fixed point data type, and I think that is the best approach.  But no matter what you tried?  Perhaps we have different understandings of fixed-point-arithmetic.

> while avoiding floating point math.

Another worth while goal, though reducing in value.  Even in embedded systems, I seldom had to deal with a processor that did not have floating point parts.  Floating point hardware has gotten reasonably good.

Any way, using fixed point avoids any need for floating point.  Even for display purposes.

I think I need to proceed with a few examples.

---

Fixed point Example 1:  Dollars and pennies

The unit of American money is based on the dollar. The Dollar **is** a fixed point data type.

So, if you have 27 dollars, how do you split it with your sibling?

One way (of several) that you all know is to convert 27 dollars into 2700 pennies. Dividing this value by 2 is trivial. Now you and your sibling can each get 1350 pennies.  (i.e. the penny is a fixed point data type, that easily converts to/from dollars, and vice-vesa)

Note that this is completely integer arithmetic.  Adding 2 integers, and dividing by 2 (any modern compiler will choose the fastest implementation.. either integer divide or perhaps right-shift-by-2) and on my desktop these 2 actions take less than a microsecond to complete.

You should waste no more time on measuring the relative performance of those two options (divide vs right-shift), you simply enable -O3 when your code tests correct.  Your compiler should be able to choose correctly.

The choice of units in any problem is based on a scale factor that covers the range of values (in your problem) AND the understandable and quickly implemented conversion between units.  And note that uint64_t can describe a large amount of cash, even in pennies.  (challenge to the student.)

---

In General, about fixed point:

Given

```
uint8_t  x = 27;
```

and the desire to divide by 2 evenly and quickly... can any scale factor be something that serves your needs?  I say yes.

---

example 2 - 50 cent coins and a dollar

How about we try, for example, a simple scale factor of 2, i.e. the unit is a hu, or half unit. (analogous to the 50-cent-coin)

```
uint8_t  x = 27 * 1/hu;   (hu = 1/2)
```

This means that 54 hu represents 27 units. (ie, it takes 54 50-cent-coins to add up to 27 dollars)

The fixed point solution is to scale your integer values to achieve the arithmetic required.  If you scale to even values, all your integers will divide evenly to the hu units.

---

example 3 - nickles and a dollar

Another possible scale might be 20, both decimal (for readability) and binary for performance. (note that there are 20 nickels in a dollar)

```
uint16  x = 27 * 1/tu;  (tu = 1/20)
```

Now 540 represents a scaled 27. i.e. 540 nickles

---

All examples are fully integer, provide exact answers, and there is a trivial mechanism to convert the values for presentation to the user.  i.e. which ever fixed point used, convert to analogue of pennies, and thus 1350 pennies.

Display the penny count as a dollar

```
 std::cout << (pennyCount / 100) << "." << (pennyCount % 100) << std::endl;
```

I think this should look something like (untested)

```
 13.50
```

Now your challenge is to make it look nice on the output.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work and should be fast:

`float y = (x >> 1) + (0.5 * (x & 0x01))`

What it does

- `(x >> 1)`  Divide by 2 using the bit shift
- `(0.5 * (x & 0x01))` Add 0.5 if the last bit was `1` (odd number)

Comment: They wanted to avoid the floating points. Nice bits though.